# nrow of resp.data and length of group are non-conformable

Tags: r

I am using lordif to test DIF of 35 items. My data matrix consists of 1 column of Sex (1,2) and the rest of columns are items. I watched video on how to use the lordif and followed the example. But when I do it myself, I kept getting the error: `nrow of resp.data and length of group are non-conformable`.

My codes are:

```
genDif = lordif(di[,2:36],di[,1],criterion='Chisqr',alpha=0.01)
```

where di is my data matrix.
The first column is Sex and rest is items. Even if when I separate response data from group membership of sex, using the following code:

```
genDif = lordif(di,sex,criterion='Chisqr',alpha=0.01)
```

I still get the error of `Error in table(group, resp) : all arguments must have the same length`

I really lost in what I did wrong. Please help.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` and pacakges uses

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to do a DIF analysis of 35 items by sex on a survey. I used r package 'lordif'. That is when the error occurs.